# Django Throws 302 error when I call API written on Questions app and redirects to /login/?next=/api/questions/tags-list/

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, http-status-code-302

I have written an API URL on questions model for retrieving a 1st 10 tags, its a get call.
When I call it from the react app, i am getting 302 to that api and redirects to

```
http://localhost:8093/login/?next=/api/questions/tags-list/
```

with 200 responses as html code for django admin panel login.

I have not implemented the authentication and it's not required.

Django - 4.2.7
I tried working on adding middlewares for the restframework and is still having the same issue

The below shown is the base app urls,

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('jet/', include('jet.urls', 'jet')), 
    path('', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'/api/questions/', include('question.urls')),
    path(r'user_auth/', include('user_auth.urls'))
]
```

The questions urls is as follows:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('/tags-list/', TagsView.as_view(), name='tags-list' ),
    path('match-tags/', MatchTags.as_view(), name='matching-tags'),
    path('presigned-urls/', PresignedURL.as_view(), name='presigned_url'),
    path('question-submission/', QuestionSubmission.as_view(), name='question-submission')
]
```

this is the view called.

```
class TagsView(APIView):
    def get(self,request):
        print("HI", flush=True)
        tags = Tag.objects.all()[:10]  # Get first 10 tags
        serializer = TagSerializer(tags, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

on settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'jet',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'user_auth',
    'corsheaders',
    'question',
    'storages',
    's3direct',
    'file'
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'user_auth.User'

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1000),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1000),
    'AUTH_USER_MODEL': 'user_auth.User'
}

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
    "GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"  
]

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
    # "Authorization",
    "Accept",
    "Accept-Language",
    "Content-Language",
    "Content-Type",
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs because when `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` is set in the Django REST Framework settings, all views are required to be authorized. If you need to exclude authentication for a particular view, you can specify `authentication_classes = []` within that view.

```
class TagsView(APIView):
   authentication_classes = []  # Disable authentication for this view
   permission_classes = [AllowAny]  # Allow any permission for this view if you have any

def get(self, request):
    print("HI", flush=True)
    tags = Tag.objects.all()[:10]  # Get first 10 tags
    serializer = TagSerializer(tags, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```